# Horizontal Multi level menu based on CSS only

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am generating Multi Level menu dynamically and want this menu to show properly without using any JavaScript of jQuery, at this stage menu is only two level.

Below is the menu structure generated dynamically

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul >
  <li><a href="/en/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu2/">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu3/">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu4/">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu5">Menu 5</a>
    <ul class="/en/menu5/menu5-1/">
      <li><a href="">Menu 5.1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu 5.2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu 5.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/en/menu6/">Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Multi level working with JS https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMrqmQ

I need a pointer to good example, i have looked for example but all of them has class defined for UL & li while my dynamic menu ul..li clean so that user can customize it based on there requirements

**UPDATE**

Working on codepen, seems to work well https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvEzwe

```
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Update another example based on pure css,

Comment: `Update another example based on pure css` , what you really want ??

Comment: It is fine now as i solved teh problem with second example, I actaully wanted to generate clean list structure with out assigning any class to parent or child items so that user can customize menu based on css. second example is fine. if i can find better example that would be nice

Comment: ok . Anyway i made a demo you can check. @learning

Comment: @AnzilkhaN, it seems to be the same css which i am using

Comment: Are you using from `codepen` version ??

Did you add `one more ul on menu 5.1` in that version ?? @Learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May be this could help**

I change some of your hover to it's nested ul. I mean add `direct child selector(>)` for hover and nested `ul` position.

```css
 .nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     background-color: #444;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
 .nav li {
     font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     line-height: 40px;
     text-align: left;
     position: relative; /* added for it's absolute child */
}
 .nav a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #fff;
     display: block;
     padding-left: 15px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
     transition: .3s background-color;
}
 .nav a:hover {
     background-color: #005f5f;
}
 .nav a.active {
     background-color: #aaa;
     color: #444;
     cursor: default;
}
/* Sub Menus */
 .nav li li {
     font-size: .8em;
}
/******************************************* Style menu for larger screens Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems or other values could be used depending on other factors ********************************************/
 @media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
     .nav li {
         width: 130px;
         border-bottom: none;
         height: 50px;
         line-height: 50px;
         font-size: 1.4em;
         display: inline-block;
         margin-right: -4px;
    }
     .nav a {
         border-bottom: none;
    }
     .nav > ul > li {
         text-align: center;
    }
     .nav > ul > li > a {
         padding-left: 0;
    }
    /* Sub Menus */
     .nav li ul {
         position: absolute;
         display: none;
         width: inherit;
    }
     .nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
         display: block;
    }
     .nav li > ul > li:hover ul { /* change hover to nested li */
         display: block; 
    }
     .nav li > ul > li ul { /* change position to it's nested parent */
         top: 0;
         right: -100%;
    }
     .nav li ul li {
         display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/en/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/menu2/">Menu 2</a>
            <ul class="/en/menu5/menu5-1/">
                <li><a href="">Menu 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Menu 2.2</a>
                    <ul class="/en/menu5/menu5-1/">
                        <li><a href="">Menu 2.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Menu 2.2.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/en/menu3/">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/menu4/">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/menu5">Menu 5</a>
            <ul class="/en/menu5/menu5-1/">
                <li><a href="">Menu 5.1</a>
                    <ul class="/en/menu5/menu5-1/">
                        <li><a href="">Menu 5.1.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Menu 5.1.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Menu 5.2</a>
                    <ul class="/en/menu5/menu5-1/">
                        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Menu 5.2.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/en/menu6/">Menu 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Learning , i add `one more nested ul` and change it's `hover` .